# Pass value with @Value to @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring-boot

So basically I have my rootFolderId in my application.properties

```
  app.property.rootFolder="some string "
```

and I need to get it in the Controller

```
 @Value("${app.property.rootFolder}")
    private static  String rootFolder ;
```

and use it in @RequestParam like :

```
@GetMapping({"/list"})
    public List<File> list(@RequestParam(defaultValue = rootFolder)  String parentId) 
{ ..../}
```

but I get the problem "Attribute value must be constant" .Is there any way to make it work ?

Comment: Why not check if parentId == null is true and assign it the config value in the controller body?

Comment: It s working this way but I wanted to see if I can pass it to the @RequestParam  as someone below did , but I couldn't think of directly passing "${app.property.rootFolder}" . Also thanks !!

Comment: If it's a property of the app, then not sure why it's being passed as a parameter to the controller method.  Seems like the property should be an injected value to a Controller field, then used within the method.

Comment: If the Get Request would not have any folderId I want to pass the rootFolderId and  though it would be the best way to pass it to Service .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use property replacement in the `@RequestParam` field.  See below.

```
@GetMapping({"/list"})
public List<File> list(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "${app.property.rootFolder}") String parentId) { ... }
```